# how to make indexes and different unique indexes in Morphia Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Using morphia, mongoDB and JAVA 8, I'm trying to make some indexes on my entity, and **some other unique indexes** on different properties. 
Lets say I want fields "a" and "b" be a regular indexes `@Indexes({@Index(fields= {@Field("a"), @Field("b")})})`.
but how I add other index field with `options = @IndexOptions(unique = true)` ?

Thanks

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518878/how-to-add-indexes-in-mongodb-project-with-morphia-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
@Indexes({@Index(fields= {@Field("a"), @Field("b")}), @Index(options= @IndexOptions(unique = true), fields= {@Field("c")})})
@Entity(collection_name)
public class IndexClass {

        @Id
        private Long id;
        private String a;
        private String b;
        private String c;

     // Getters and Setters

}
```

Start up code:

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia(); 
morphia.map(IndexClass.class); 
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(); 
Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(client, db_name); 
datastore.ensureIndexes();
```

Comment: thanks, it does build successfully, but the indexes are not really created